# Auto populate based on a price list

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I have a price list on a worksheet that has columns as follows
TYPE - ITEM - JOB COST - PART COSTS - PROFIT

On a second sheet (job log), when i select the 'item' from a drop down, i want the other values, from the price list, to populate on the job log sheet

Comment: have a look on VLOOKUP (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula:
`=VLOOKUP(A2,'Price List'!$B$2:$E$6,2,FALSE)`

A2 is the item you choose from the drop down list in Job Log
'Price List'!$B$2:$E$6  is the array Data in Price List  ITEM - JOB COST - PART COSTS - PROFIT without row header (if you need Type you have to write it after Item column on the right)
2 is the column you want to extract result from (job cost if your data is in the following order Item (1), Job Cost(2), Part Costs(3)...)
You can drag it down